# Close windows explorer window with Auto hotkey

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

I'm unable to find method to close path open in windows explorer. Lets say I would like to close opened window, "c:\program files". Code should look like

```
#::j

    close window "c:\program files"

return
```

Thank you.

Comment: if `winclose` doesnt work, wasnt there a `winkill`   command? or you could kill a window with a parameter in winclose, dont remember

Comment: finally, you could also try sending `!F4` to the specified window using `controlsend`. But I guess you're not catching the window properly. Try other  commands like `winminimize` first.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look here:

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm

which specifies:

`WinClose [, WinTitle, WinText, SecondsToWait, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]`

and then:

```
#j::  ;  Win Key + j
    WinClose, C:\Program Files  ;  close Program Files window
return
```

Alternatively, to close any explorer window, use:

```
#j::  ;  Win Key + j
    WinClose, ahk_class CabinetWClass  ;  closes any explorer window
return
```

Hth

Comment: This code snipped is not working. Window is not closing.

Comment: Sorry, I edited above to something that works for me: `WinClose, C:\Program Files` (removed the quotes).  Also, the general class of explorer windows is called `CabinetWClass` so this will work to close ANY open explorer window: `WinClose, ahk_class CabinetWClass` (as mentioned by @ahkcoder you can also check for a given title).  Hth,

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code and here is a [video stepping through the code](http://sendvid.com/a8v4jrd4):

```
path := "C:\Program Files"

shell := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")
shell.open("file:///c:/")
shell.open("file:///" . path) 


#If WinExist("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; explorer

    F1::
    for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
       if (path == window.Document.Folder.Self.Path)
            window.quit()
    return

#If
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, but opened window is still not closing.

Comment: The code I posted above is the best method of interfacing with Windows Explorer. If this is not working at all, than something is wrong with your Operating system, or you have a virus/malware. In either case you may want to do a system wipe and try reinstalling a legal version of Windows.